# How to cut a part of a matrix in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

Let's say you have a vector of vectors (a matrix) in Racket and you are only interested in a specific part of it (like 3x3 out of a 5x5 matrix).
How can you "take" that part of that matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vector-copy`.

```
#lang racket

(define A (vector (vector 11 12 13 14 15)
                  (vector 21 22 23 24 25)
                  (vector 31 32 33 34 35)
                  (vector 41 42 43 44 45)))

(for/vector ([i (in-range 1 3)])      ; row 1 and 2
  (vector-copy (vector-ref A i) 1 4)) ; columns 1, 2 and 3
```

The result:

```
'#(#(22 23 24) 
   #(32 33 34))
```

Comment: Thank you! How does this actually work? 
Why did you write "[row A]"?

Comment: Looking at it again, I see that it doesn't work!
I have modifed the solution to use `(vector-ref A i)` to get the ith row, and then use `vector-copy` to copy the relevant columns.